# Go: convert reflect.Value of type uuid.UUID (satori) back to uuid.UUID again

Tags: go, reflection, type-conversion, uuid

I'm trying to convert a reflected UUID back to an actual UUID object again but can't find a way, when I print the reflected value it looks correct, but when trying to convert I can't find a way.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "reflect"

  uuid "github.com/satori/go.uuid"
)

func main() {
  value := uuid.Must(uuid.NewV4())
  reflectedValue := reflect.ValueOf(value)
  fmt.Println(reflectedValue)
  result := reflectedValue.String()
  fmt.Println(result)
}
```

output:

```
$ go run main.go
0cca93f8-1763-4816-a2a0-09e7aeeb674c
<uuid.UUID Value>
```

How to convert reflectedValue to uuid.UUID directly or []byte/string so I can make a uuid.UUID object from that. Since fmt.Println manages to print the correct value it has to be possible to make the conversion, but I can't figure out how.

It seem like the uuid.UUID object has a data structure of 16 uint8 values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) on the [underlying value](https://godoc.org/reflect#Value.Interface):

```
u, ok := reflectedValue.Interface().(uuid.UUID)
```